# How do I take a screenshot on Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, screen-capture

I need to capture a screenshot of Apple TV to send a bug to a developer. How do I take a screenshot in tvOS on the new Apple TV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the Apple TV connected to your development machine via USB:

**Steps**

1. Launch **Xcode** from the menu select Window → Devices
2. Select the Apple TV on the left representing your device.
3. On the device, configure the screen the way you want to capture it.
4. Click on the **Take Screenshot** button.
5. It will save the screenshot on Desktop.

For reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/capture_screenshots_from_device.html

Answer (score 5):

I would just snap a picture of the TV screen with a smartphone (or any other) camera and use this for the bug report.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with tvOS 11 and later running on a 4th-gen Apple TV/Apple TV HD or an Apple 4K, and a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13 or later, you can take a screenshot of Apple TV wirelessly and without installing any app in macOS (even Xcode, or any other app for that matter).

Follow the below steps:

1. Make sure your Apple TV and Mac are connected to the same Ethernet/Wi-Fi network.
2. On your Mac, launch the built-in QuickTime Player.app.
3. In the QuickTime Player menu bar, go to File menu → New Movie Recording or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
4. This would open a Quick Time window with the Mac's camera turned on by default (if you have one connected to your Mac or if you are using a MacBook with one built-in FaceTime HD camera).
5. Now, click on the arrow besides the red circular Record button and select your Apple TV for Camera.

   [image]
6. This would start mirroring Apple TV's screen in QuickTime Player on your Mac. The Apple TV on the connected display would start showing a think red-colored border indicating that a screen mirroring is in progress.

   [image]

   (The above photo shows an Apple TV connected to a monitor over HDMI, and QuickTime Player.app in movie recording mode running on a MacBook Pro which is connected to the same Wi-Fi network as the Apple TV. The Mac and Apple TV are not physically connected to each other.)
7. This is how the Apple TV mirror in QuickTime Player.app on your Mac would appear.

   [image]
8. Now click anywhere inside the QuickTime Player.app window to dismiss the player controls. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to take a screenshot. This would change the cursor into a crosshair.

   Move the cursor over to the QuickTime Player.app window, and press <kbd>Space</kbd> key to highlight the window. This would further change the cursor into a camera. Now either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or left click on Mouse or Trackpad to capture the screenshot. This would save the screenshot on Desktop (or any other location configured for screen capture)

   [image]
9. Voila! Your Apple TV screenshot is captured, without fiddling with cables, or installing any additional apps.